# When loading page how to selected one radio button as default?

Tags: angularjs, html

Radio button code here my code

```
<ion-radio ng-model="data.gender" ng-required="true" ng-value="'male'">Male</ion-radio>

<ion-radio ng-model="data.gender" ng-required="true" ng-value="'female'">Female</ion-radio>
```

hope angular js help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-init` to solve your problem, The `ng-init` directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope

```
<ion-radio ng-init="data.gender = 'male'" ng-model="data.gender" ng-required="true" ng-value="'male'" name="gender">Male</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="data.gender" ng-required="true" ng-value="'female'" name="gender">Female</ion-radio>
```

**OR**

```
$scope.data.gender = 'male';
```

Answer (score 5):

you can define initial value in your controller on load this html template.
just need to add

```
$scope.data.gender = 'male';
```

Answer (score 4):

in your template where you are defining ng-controller, you can define `ng-init="radioInit()"` and in your controller have that function as:

---

```
$scope.radioInit = function() {
  $scope.data.gender = 'male'; 
//or
  $scope.data.gender = 'female';
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to define

One is : Inside View

```
ng-init="data.gender = 'male'"
```

Two is : Inside Controller

```
$scope.data = {
     gender = 'male'
}
```

Comment: gender = male is not the correct syntax. Should be gender: 'male'